# rails-jquery-autocomplete search for school_name but save school_id

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I have an app where students belong to schools. I am trying to create the sign up form so that they start typing the name of their school and it autocompletes with their school, from a database of schools I have.

I have got the rails-jquery-autocomplete gem working well, however it won't seem to save the school id when the user hits submit.

The parameters that are being sent are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "user"=>{"first_name"=>"test",
 "email"=>"test@test.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "birthday(3i)"=>"15",
 "birthday(2i)"=>"4",
 "birthday(1i)"=>"1990",
 "school_id"=>"Chiswick Community School",
 "commit"=>"SIGN UP"}
```

so as you can see the school_id is being populated with the school name, not id.

The code I have for the form object is:

```
<div class="form-object">
      <%= f.autocomplete_field :school_id, autocomplete_school_name_users_path, placeholder: 'school/college' %>
</div>
```

How can I get this to show the name of the school to the user, but save just the school_id?

I have looked around for ages and how found some mentions of using a hidden_field tag under the autocomplete_field but I have tried this and can't seem to get it to work, so I don't even know if it is the right approach

(I tried it like this: `<%= f.hidden_field :school_id, id: 'school_id' %>`)

Comment: What gem are you using exactly, there is [jquery-autocomplete-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-autocomplete-rails), [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) etc but no `jQuery-rails-autocomplete`. Use the name from your `Gemfile`

Comment: rails-jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [gem docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rails-jquery-autocomplete/1.0.0) 
using the `id_element` option will update the targeted field with the id of the selected object.

```
<div class="form-object">
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :school_name, 
       autocomplete_school_name_users_path, 
       placeholder: 'school/college',
       id_element: '#school_id' # can be any jQuery selector.
  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :school_id, id: 'school_id' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I have not actually tested this - milage may vary.

Comment: Ah, ok, I hadn't really understood that I needed to use the id_element WITH the hidden_field. I had tried both by themselves and they hadn't worked. Now it does!